# how to add Thai as system language Samsung J5

Tags: languages

Can someone please walk me through how to add Thai as a setup language on my wifes new Samsung J5? As I understand it the language will be there somewhere and just need unlocking

Answer (score -1):

You need to go to Settings > Languages and Input > Languages and then select Thai as the language.

Comment: I think he wants to add Thai if it's not already there, i.e., it won't be in that dropdown.   To do what I think he wants probably means he has to root the device.

Comment: Yes. Or you could wait for Google to add Thai language.